# How to log data from third party diagnostic logger in .net core (SSH.NET)

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.diagnostics, ssh.net

I wish to add a diagnostic logger in .net core 6 but nothing that I tried seems to work, that good old way using `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="SshNet.Logging">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="Console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

I tried adding trace source:

```
static TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("SshNet.Logging");
[SwitchAttribute("SshNetSwitch", typeof(SourceSwitch))]
...
 SourceSwitch sourceSwitch = new SourceSwitch("SourceSwitch", "Verbose");
                ts.Switch = sourceSwitch;
                int idxConsole = ts.Listeners.Add(new System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener());
                ts.Listeners[idxConsole].Name = "console";
```

which didn't work.

Important to mention that I defined the following variables:

```
#define DEBUG
#define FEATURE_DIAGNOSTICS_TRACESOURCE
#define TRACE
```

Any ideas?